# How to think column based when preparing data to be inserted to a dataframe (and exported to Parquet)

Tags: python, parquet, python-polars, pyarrow, duckdb

**Preface**

I am extracting several TB worth of tabular data that is now stored in encrypted text files, to be decrypted and ingested into duckdb. It seems like duckdb works best with Parquet, which again points to using polars or pandas to create the Parquet file. Since I am using multiprocessing to extract the data I think the best alternative is to store it as files, then have a single process read the files into DuckDB.

Now the script is looping over each file of the raw-data, decrypting it and and putting it in a list of list (row based) - then a Polars df is created from the data and it is written to Parquet. As this seems a bit cumbersome and takes some time, I am looking for options:

```
encrypted:(val1a, val1b, val1c) -> encryptedlineoftext
encrypted:(val2a, val2b, val2c) -> encryptedlineoftext
```

```py
for file in files:
    decryptedData = []
    for line in file:
        (decryptlogic)
        decryptedData.append([val1a, val1b, val1c,(..)])
    (..)
    df = pl.DataFrame(decryptedData, schema=columns)
    df.write_parquet(..)
```

**Question**

Since Polars df are column based, would it be better to store each column in an array:

```py
colA = [val1a, val2a, val3a, (..)]
colB = [val1b, val2b, val3b, (..)]
```

instead of:

```py
decryptedData = [[val1a, val1b, (..)],[val2a, val2b, (..)]]
```

As the data would already be column stored? I must admit that I am a bit afraid of missing values in any of the columns (this isn't really expected) that would make the columns shifted:

```py
colA = [val1a, val3a, (..)]
colB = [val1b, val2b, val3b]
```

The data in itself has the same columns for each row and is row based.
I guess one way of doing that would be to have checks that all of the data that is to be inserted have a value before they are inserted into their respective columns (and if not, either skip that line of data entirely, or insert a blank data point to the column:

```py
for file in files:
    decryptedData = []
    for line in file:
        val1a, val1b, val1c, (..) = decrypt(line)
        if val1a is not none, val1b is not none (..):
            colA.append(val1a)
            colB.append(val1b)
            colC.append(val1c)
    (..)
    df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
    "A": colA,
    "B": colB,
    "C": colC,
     }
     )
     df.write_parquet(..)
```

I think this can be done a bit more pretty and efficient using dictionaries, but my main point of concern if this is a better (faster) way of doing it, and if it is safe enough (since the only thing that I can see guarantees the relation between the values in `colA, colB, colC (..)` is the shared index across several lists).

Edit:
After reviewing a bit - some times two lines can be dependent on each other so I think a generator going line for line cannot be done.

Comment: Do you need the lists at all? Could you not create the dataframe in one go using a generator? `df = pl.DataFrame((decrypt(line) for line in file), schema=columns)`

Comment: @jqurious Thank you for your input, that is an intriguing suggestion! Since the code allways have revolved around having a function that opens a file and iterate through all the lines I must admit I have never though about thinking purely line wise like that. Is using generators for creating dataframes also good from a performance perspective?

Comment: Sorry @jqurious - I have been misleading in the question. I just remembered that some data can be split over two lines which is handled in the decrypt logic - but I guess that means you cannot really just look at one line at the time as I said. I updated my question.

Comment: I edited in pyarrow tag because there are likely some good pyarrow solutions as pyarrow has more comprehensive support for writing files and datasets. polars is really geared towards being a dataframe library. It's not intended as middleware to write parquet files.

Comment: A few clarifying questions, what are your bottlenecks. From context it seems your TBs of data are already in small enough files such that you don't have memory constraints. Have you tried parallelization? Have you tried using [cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) which may help if there is repetition at the expense of memory?

Comment: I did some testing on a larger dataset (10_000_000 rows) and there does seem to be quite a difference. Create a dataframe using the "column approach" in your example is 2x faster than the "row approach" (list or generator).

Comment: Thank you so much @DeanMacGregor - good point. I do the extraction process using multiple processes - after profiling a bit - one month of data takes 10 minutes to extract and save to parquet, and 50 minutes to ingest in database. So this might not be the biggest bottleneck.